# Moving Tkinter Window Prevents Resizing on Pack()

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, window

If I am clicking on a Tkinter window and moving it around (even just 1px as a result of the mouse click), then the window doesn't resize properly on pack creation. It also jumps the window back to where it was at the start of the drag, rather than where it was when the creation event occurred.

For instance, here is an example of properly functioning behavior where I use the `after` function to change the contents of a frame from holding the green button to holding the grey button:

[image] ==[GOES TO]==> [image]

If, however, I'm holding down my mousing and moving the window around, this is what happens:

[image] ==[GOES TO]==> [image]

I don't know if you can tell, but the window failed to adjust its size, causing the bottom "Stop Experiment" button to be cut off and the "Click Me" button to be smaller than it should be.

How can I ensure that the window resizes properly even if a user is in the middle of dragging it around at the time? I tried `root.update()` but that didn't work.

Here is a slightly condensed version of my code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class MyGui:

    def __init__(self, font=None):  
    
        self.root = tk.Tk()

        self.font = "Arial 12"
        self.font_bold = self.font + " bold"

    def makeLabel(self, text, parent = None):
        
        label = tk.Label(parent, text=text, font=self.font)
        label.pack(fill=tk.X)
    
        return label
        
    def makeButton(self, text, parent, command = None, **style_arguments):
        
        button = tk.Button(parent, text=text, command=command, **style_arguments)
        button.pack(fill=tk.X)
    
        return button

    def makeFrame(self, parent, **style_arguments):
    
        frame = tk.Frame(parent, **style_arguments)
        frame.pack(fill="both")
        
        return frame

    def start(self):
        
        self.root.mainloop()
        
    def stop(self):
        
        self.root.quit()
        self.root.destroy()
```

and

```
def main():

        gui = MyGui()

    gui.makeLabel("Experiment is running", parent = gui.root)
    
    frame_container = gui.makeFrame(parent = gui.root)
    
    gui.makeButton('TIME LEFT: 0', fg = "white", bg = "green", 
                                 font = gui.font_bold, 
                                 parent = frame_container)
                            
    frame_container.after(4000, lambda: switchIt(gui, frame_container))
    
    gui.makeButton('STOP EXPERIMENT', fg = "white", bg = "red", 
                    font = gui.font_bold, parent = gui.root,
                    command = gui.stop)

    gui.start()

def switchIt(gui, frame_container):
    
    # Remove placeholder widgets (if any)
    for child in frame_container.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    
    gui.makeButton(
                         "CLICK ME",
                         parent = frame_container, 
                         height=5, width = 40)
    gui.root.update()
```

main()

where `main()` is what gets executed.

(Note: For minimally reproducible, I took out the code that counts down the text time, so that will just show 0, even though the `after` function still applies and will switch the screen in appx 4s).

Comment: Provide a complete working minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Art I thought I had. Try now

Comment: This might be because it cannot calculate the size required when resizing the window. What you could try is to store the size before deleting the button (`size = gui.root.winfo_geometry()`) and then use `gui.root.after(30, gui.root.geometry, size)`

Comment: But would that help? Your method seems like it would work if I wanted to restore the size of the window to what it was before deleting/adding widgets. However, I do not. I want to have the window dynamically resize when a widget is deleted or added, but it does not resize at all if the mouse button is depressed.

Comment: (I said depressed above but I meant if the window is being dragged even a little bit)

Answer (score 0):

One solution to preventing the window from refusing to resize when a widget is created or destroyed if it was currently being dragged around at the same time is to briefly disable the title bar and then reenable it after the destroy/creation event.

For instance, change the `switchIt()` function as follows:

```
def switchIt(gui, frame_container):

    self.gui.root.overrideredirect(True) # <========= ADDED
    
    # Remove placeholder widgets (if any)
    for child in frame_container.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    
    gui.makeButton( "CLICK ME", parent = frame_container, height=5, width = 40)
                         
    self.gui.root.overrideredirect(False) # <========= ADDED
```

The `overrideredirect()` function will remove the title bar if set to `True` and return the title bar if set to `False`. **Dragging is only possible if the title bar is enabled.** So what you're essentially doing is making drag not possible for a brief time. As a bonus, the dragging done up to that point is retained (the window doesn't leap back to the beginning of its motion as it did before).

This goes sufficiently fast that it's not noticeable by the user, since any window adjustment gets wrapped into the greater adjustment of the destroy/create.

The one downside is that the mouse loses its tie to the title bar, so the window stops dragging when the create/destroy event takes place (that is, when the `overrideredirect(True)` is called). This does not feel unnatural though since it seems a valid response to the window content change, and it's easy enough to restart drag again if needed since the title bar will reappear almost instantly.